# Display drive letter with disk space

Tags: powershell

I'm just trying to display the drive letter with the freespace from this. I'm pretty sure I need to include it in the ForEach, but not sure how. Right now all I get is the free disk space.

```
Get-WMIObject Win32_LogicalDisk -Filter "DeviceID='C:' or DeviceID='D:' or DeviceID='L:'" | ForEach-Object {[math]::truncate($_.freespace / 1GB)}
33
33
33
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Get-WMIObject Win32_LogicalDisk -Filter "DeviceID='C:' or DeviceID='D:' or DeviceID='L:'" | Select DeviceID,@{N='FreeSpace';E={[math]::truncate($_.freespace / 1GB)}}

DeviceID    FreeSpace
--------    ---------
C:                 75
D:                  0
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `ForEach-Object`, use `Select-Object` and place your free space calculation inside a [calculated property](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730948.aspx) expression instead:

```
Get-WmiObject ...| Select-Object DeviceID,@{Name='FreeSpace';Expression={[math]::Truncate($_.FreeSpace / 1GB)}
```